# IE10 XML does not get formatted inside iframe

Tags: html, xml, iframe, internet-explorer-10

I am writing a simple HTML file. I would like to embed an XML in it. I do this using iFrames. In IE9 the XML is formatted (though it shows activeX warnings). If I run the same code in IE10 I do NOT see the formatting at all. I see only the XML content. However if I open the XML separately I am able to see the formatting.

How do I get the formatting in IE10 inside iframe? Thanks in advance.

Here is my HTML code

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test Code</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <iframe src="sample.xml"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

And my sample.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<test>asd</test>
```

--
Update: Switching the browser to IE8 Standards mode works.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```

Is this the only solution or is there an IE10 based better solution for this?

Comment: Is there any error in the console? (press F12, refresh the page and select the console tab in the debugger window)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We just had this problem, and found a bunch of questions like this with no answers!  Finally we found the answer from Microsoft [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/799821/xml-is-rendered-as-html-when-loaded-into-an-iframe-via-iframe-src-url):  System working as designed :-(

From our friends at Microsoft:

> As of IE9, IE has had native support for rendering XML content
>   including XHTML and SVG. To avoid conflicts with this native support,
>   the auto-generated tree view for XML was scoped to only apply to
>   top-level documents. Thus, when XML content is hosted inside an
>   IFRAME, a tree view will not automatically be generated by default.
>   However, when the browser is running in Compatibility View, IE tries
>   to more closely emulate the behavior of previous releases, which is
>   why the tree view is still displayed under these circumstances.

Comment: We just moved our little xml viewer to a new window instead of an IFrame.  Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

A php file can read the xml file then compile the xml coloring and output the html code, maybe.